# sqlite returning nothing after 2nd cursor.fetchall()

Tags: python, sqlite

Why do I get nothing when I execute cursor.fetchall() twice after a cursor.execute()? Is there anyway of preventing this from happening? Do I need to store the information on a variable? Is it suppose to work this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fetchall` does what it says--it fetches all.  There's nothing left after that.  To get more results, you'd need to run another query (or the same query again).

From the python [db-api 2.0 specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

> ```
> cursor.fetchall() 
>
>         Fetch all (remaining) rows of a query result, returning
>         them as a sequence of sequences (e.g. a list of tuples).
>         Note that the cursor's arraysize attribute can affect the
>         performance of this operation.
>
> cursor.fetchone() 
>
>         Fetch the next row of a query result set, returning a
>         single sequence, or None when no more data is
>         available. [6]
> ```

Comment: But then, what is "one"? one item of the retrieved query?

Comment: @relima: "one item of the retrieved query?"  What else could it be?

Comment: @S.Lott: I don't know why I got so confused over this, thanks.