# How to put the variables of a mysql table in a list?

Tags: python, mysql, list

I have a mysql table which looks like this:

```
type   -   car   -   country   -   value   
A      -   VW    -   DE        -   50
D      -   AU    -   US        -   30
E      -   MC    -   SA        -   4
```

I'm trying to create the values of  `type, car, country` and `value` in a list.
This is my code:

```py
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import os

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    passwd = '****.',
    database = 'cars_db'
    )

cursor = mydb.cursor()

select = "SELECT * FROM `table_cars`"
select_all = cursor.execute(select)

type= [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
car = [i[1] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
country  = [i[3] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
value = [i[4] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
    
print(type)
print(car)
print(country)
print(value)
```

This is my outcome:

```
InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
```

This is what I expected:

```
['A', 'D', 'E']
['VW', 'AU', 'MC']
['DE', 'US', 'SA']
['50', '30', '4']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlite returning nothing after 2nd cursor.fetchall()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150957/sqlite-returning-nothing-after-2nd-cursor-fetchall) i.e.  once you've fetched all there's nothing left to fetch

Comment: @JeffUK so I should use Fetchone instead of Fetchall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fetch your result before the lists. See below:

```
select = "SELECT * FROM `table_cars`"
res = cursor.execute(select)
select_all = res.fetchall()

type= [i[0] for i in select_all]
car = [i[1] for i in select_all]
country  = [i[3] for i in select_all]
value = [i[4] for i in select_all]
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'`

Comment: This means that your SQL result is None. Are you sure for the validity of your SQL query? For example why 'table_cars' is inside quotes in your query?

Comment: How can I check that? There are some None values in my table yea. Thats correct. How should my sql query look like then?

Comment: Firstly, try to run the sql query without quotes for table_cars: `select = "SELECT * FROM table_cars"`

Comment: Already fixed it thank you. I placed the fetchall in a seperate variable not in the execute.

Comment: Great. However it's strange, as it should run in same line too. If your problem was resolved, please accept the answer, so that it will be removed from Unanswered que. Cheers

Comment: If you edit your answer I can accept it. Make it like this:

`select = "SELECT * FROM `table_cars`"
 select_all = cursor.execute(select)
 data = cursor.fetchall()
 type= [i[0] for i in data]
 car = [i[1] for i in data]
 country  = [i[3] for i in data]
 value = [i[4] for i in data]`

Comment: I added fetchall in new line. However it is strange that didn't work in same line

Comment: I dont understand it either. I think the cursor doenst have a fetchall option. Actually dont need to put the cursor in a variable. Now you should UP my question because I accepted your anser lo l:)